# ASP.NET was the checkbox was checked in repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater with html table inside. In the html table I have a table cell with a check box.

I am trying to get the checked rows from the user after clicking a button but the result is always null.

asp.net markup:

```
<table id="tbl1" class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>test 1</th>
        <th>test 2</th>
        <th>test 3</th>
        <th>test 4</th>
        <th>Select</th>
    </tr>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr id="tr1" runat="server">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("test1") %>'>' ></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("test2") %>'>' ></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("test3") %>'>' ></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("test4") %>'>' ></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td id="td1" runat="server">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="Select" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
<asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="Go" OnClick="btnSelect_Click" />
```

C# code:

```
protected void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem rpt in rep.Items)
    {
        CheckBox ckb = (CheckBox)rpt.FindControl("Select");

        if (ckb.Checked) // Always Null
        {
            //
        }
        else
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean `ckb` is null?

Comment: I don't work with Web Forms for a few years, so I don't remember exactly. But I think you have to find the table, then the checkbox, i.e. `HTMLElement table = (HTMLElement)rpt.FindControl("tr1"); CheckBox ckb = (CheckBox)table.FindControl("Select");`. You can also write an recursive FindControl.

Comment: Why have you set your table rows to `runat="server"`? `CheckBox.Checked` is a bool and can't be null, do you mean `ckb` is null, i.e. it is not finding the control.

Comment: set Autopostback="true" in Checkbox

Comment: i have runat-"server" because i have itemdatabound to change class for the td with an if statement

Comment: yes, cbk is Null, i tried your code but still, not working.

Comment: if i put the check box to Autopostback="true" when i check one of the boxes it get remove immediately

Comment: added if(!IsPostBack) fixed the issue for this thing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have another server control inside the repeater item. The Checkbox is not directly in the repeater item it is in the table row. You can extract the checkbox like this

```
CheckBox ckb = (CheckBox)rpt.FindControl("tr1").FindControl("Select");

if (ckb.Checked)
...
```

Of course this is bad since changing the layout will break your code. To remedy this you can write a recursive FindControl but it requires some more work.

Comment: And how is the if statement goes ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you rebinding the DataSource for the Repeater on PostBack? This would cause the state of all the controls in the Repeater to be reset.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that `rpt.FindControl("Select")` only searches only in the children of `rpt`. You can try this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Iterates throug all children and returns all of Type T.
/// </summary>
public static List<T> FindChildrenOfType<T>(Control control) where T : class
{
    List<T> controls = new List<T>();

    foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
    {
        if (childControl.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            controls.AddRange(FindChildrenOfType<T>(childControl, comp));
        }

        if (childControl is T)
        {
            controls.Add(childControl as T);
        }
    }

    return controls;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var checkboxes = FindChildrenOfType<CheckBox>(rpt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this....

Aspx Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CategoryID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("val") %>' />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:Button Text="Click" OnClick="Button2_Click" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CS Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
              DataTable dt = new DataTable();
              dt.Columns.Add("val", typeof(string));

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
              dt.Rows.Add("testing" + i.ToString());

       Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
       Repeater1.DataBind();
           }
        }     

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string Rpt = "Repeater Items Checked:<br />";
                for (int i = 0; i < Repeater1.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("CategoryID");
                    if (chk.Checked)
                    {
                        Rpt += (chk.Text + "<br />");
                    }
                }
                Response.Write(Rpt);
            }
```

Refrenced By: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/534719/GetplusSelectedplusCheckboxesplusinplusASPplusRepe